# Product alignment issues Woocommerce

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi there i am haveing some issues with aligning my product images on my store front

I have added a bit of code into my custom css with no avail:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product,
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
  min-height: 293px !important;
}
```

It helped a bit but i do still have some floating up and down on my product pages and it is driving me insane.  Any tips would help us

Example of the worst case :  http://monkeybusinessvapor.com/product-category/accessories/

Comment: It's not the images that are the issue. You have an inconsistent height of titles/prices. Best way to resolve is use js for equal height (or flexbox). Alternatively, you could put the title/price below quick view (image, quickview, title, price - in that order).

Comment: flex-box i think should work perfectly here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want quick the flexbox route...

[image]

```
ul.products {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
}
ul.products li{
    padding-bottom: 20px !important; 
   /*because woocommerce-mod overwrites it*/
}
a.yith-wcqv-button.button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

You'll have to make some adjustments and put in browser prefixes - I did quick and dirty with align-items.

Comment: Woocommerce must be overriding it, i added in the developers tools

Comment: ul.products {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
        -ms-flex-align: stretch;
            align-items: stretch;
}
ul.products li{
    padding-bottom: 30px !important; 
}
a.yith-wcqv-button.button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

Comment: That worked awesome, thank you!  I had entered into my themes custom css, tried again in my child theme and works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can do it the easy way with [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Of course in Woocommerce case  you have to override CSS (unfortunately)

Eg.:

```
.woocommerce ul.products {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.woocommerce li.product {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product a.button {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```